# How do I write code to convert Binary to Decimal and back in Xcode?

Tags: binary

How do I write code to convert Binary to Decimal and back in Xcode?

I want to make a binary to decimal calculator, but I don't know how to convert Binary to Decimal in code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal number is equal to the sum of binary digits times their power of 2.

For eg --> binaryNumber = 10011 (base:2) can be converted to decimal by decimalNumber = (1*(2^4))+(0*(2^3))+(0*(2^2))+(1*(2^1))+(1*(2^0)) (base:10)

I'll write the code in JAVA for your reference

For Binary to Decimal:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
  int binaryNumber = 10011 ;
  static int sum = 0;

  BinaryToDecimal(binaryNumber,0);
}

//Here we are calculating from right to left
public static void BinaryToDecimal(int number, int power){
   int digitAtPosition = number%(10);
   sum = sum + (digitAtPosition * (2^(power)));
   while(number/10 != 0){
      BinaryToDecimal(number/10, power+1);
   }
}
```

Now similarly for Decimal to Binary conversion,

We will have a decimal number. First you will have to keep on dividing the number until the quotient becomes zero. Then from those steps we can get the binary number equivalent of the given decimal.

For eg --> we have a decimalNumber = 13 (base:10).

13/2    Quotient:6     Remainder:1

6/2    Quotient:3     Remainder:0

3/2    Quotient:1     Remainder:1

1/2    Quotient:0     Remainder:1

The binary equivalent is found by writing the remainder numbers from backwards, i,e 1101 (base:2)

In Java (For Decimal to binary)

```
public static void main(String [] args){
  int decimalNumber = 13;
  static int [] remainders = new int[size];
  static int arrayPos = 0;

  DecimalToBinary(decimalNumber);
}
public static DecimalToBinaryConverter(int number){
  remainders[arrayPos++]=number%2;
  while(number/2 > 0){
    DecimalToBinaryConverter(number/2);
  }
}
```

Now if you print the array in reverse you'll get the binary value.